# HTML2PDF is not working propertly with this code in PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, html2pdf

I tried to generate a PDF with this code but is displaying this error when try to generate it

`The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

I checked the logs file but there is nothing there about this

```
include '../../BarCodeGenerator/BarCodeGenerator.php';
include '../../BarCodeGenerator/BarcodeGeneratorPNG.php';

$generator = new \Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
$nombre = 'Test';
$precio = 20;
$codigo = "XX545858";

require_once '../../html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php';
ob_start();

$html .= '<div style="width: 200px; text-align: center;">';
$html .= '<h5 style="margin: 0; padding:0;">My website</h5>';
$html .= '<h5 style="margin: 0; padding:0;">Description</h5>';
$html .= '<h4 style="margin: 0;; padding:0; font-size: 1.3em;">'.ucwords($nombre).'</4>';
$html .= '<img style="width: 150px; height: 50px;" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($generator->getBarcode($codigo, $generator::TYPE_CODE_128)) . '">';
$html .= '<h4 style="margin: 0; padding:0; font-size: 1.1em;">' . $codigo . ' - '.number_format($precio, 2).'</h4>';
$html .= '</div>';

$pdf = ob_get_clean();
$pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr', array(mL, mT, mR, mB));
$pdf->writeHTML($html);
$pdf->Output('myfile.pdf');
```

I tried removing all about the BarCodeGenerator but still nothing but when I print the `$html` variable it prints what is suppose to be

If I write HTML code directly here `$pdf->writeHTML('<h1>Example</h1>');` it works and generate the PDF so I guess the problem is with my HTML code but I can't see what is wrong, hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: First, when you get that error message, the detailed error has been suppressed. You need to figure out what that error message is, or you're going to get nowhere. Second, you might want to check into your HTML2PDF object, to see if it has any error reporting built in.

Comment: enable error reporting php, to see where is the problem